# Why do I keep getting the SAME error in ALL meanstack projects: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I have been following multiple tutorials on meanstack apps implementing simple CRUD functionalities. I have downloaded several of their complete projects from Github, installed the modules and ran the apps.
I always get this error in the console in the HomePage:

> :3000/certain_name:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Here's the projects codes:

> [Project1 Github](https://github.com/zeptobook/Angular7CRUDz)   [Project2 Github](https://github.com/daoudaDiallo/NoteProjetAngular)   [Project3 Github](https://github.com/didinj/mean-stack-angular6-crud-example)

What is really confusing me is that is the SAME error with EVERY project. So it must have something to do with my pc configuration/vs code configuration ... something else in my configuration?
I don't think there's any problem with the projects code. You can check them out on Github. They should be fully functional.
Any idea what may be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Connection ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED means, that your service which you are trying to access is not running. Are you sure that your projects are running?

Comment: I runned the apps using ng serve -o

Comment: Try running npm start

Comment: That is not how you run Angular projects

Comment: It depends on the package.json. I found this on http://mean.io/ that you have to run the mean stack app with npm start. If this doesn't work you have to look in the package.json under scripts. if it's not start you need to run: npm run "nameOfTheScript". I can point it out for you if you could show me the package.json of the project you would like to run.

Comment: Okay! Thanks for the info :)

Comment: I believe you are right! I just found this tutorial: